# Android accessing an object in multiple activities

Tags: java, android

I am working on a calendar application.  It has multiple activities but they all rely on a Calendar object named myCalendar, which stores and sorts Date objects.  I need to be able to access this object from multiple activities.  However, I also need to be able to update myCalendar as the user creates new Date objects and adds them to myCalendar.

What is the best way to create this Object so that every activity has access to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, since you have to create a Singleton so that your class could not be instantiated more than one time and it will give you a global access to it.

You can learn more about Singletons [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/singleton-class-java/)

Answer (score 0):

You can define all members of your object as static.

Answer (score 0):

Euh you can define your calendar object as a Global Variable by extending the Application class, and in mApplication create a static reference to it, and some statics methode to access your object and update it

```
public class MApplication extends Application {
private static YoureObject yrobjct;

 public static void doChanges() {
   // do chages to your object
   }        
 }
```

And your object (here your calendar) can be access from any activity.

you have also to add this in your Manifest.xml

```
<application
 android:name=".mApplication" 
 android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
 android:label="@string/app_name">
```